# How to enable using commands on remote host using ssh without password?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudosh

i set up to use ssh between two hosts without password.

ssh log in is working fine but execute commands failed with the below erro:

```
**isn't allowed to be executed with process or redirect controls.**
```

Simple command used:

```
ssh remo-tehost " echo \"\test\"  >> \"/home/alarmstest.log\" "
```

Running trace i got:

```
debug1: Sending command:  echo "test"  >> "/home/alarmstest.log" 
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 117
```

there is sudosh on the remote server for the user used
user:x:500:500::/home/user:/usr/local/bin/sudosh
authorized_keys from the remote server + key inside
-rw------- 1 user user 9092 Dec 13 07:53 authorized_keys

Comment: `ssh` working fine, however running `ssh` with commands not working ... not the same case in this question

Comment: What happens if you prefix your command with "-t" ?

Comment: ssh -t remo-tehost " echo \"\test\"  >> \"/home/alarmstest.log\" "
output
" echo "\test"  >> "/home/alarmstest.log" " isn't allowed to be executed with process or redirect controls.
Connection to remote-host closed.

Comment: I would check the "PermitTTY" setting on the server, usually found in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config".

Comment: Does the remote system have `sudosh` installed? Does the remote user have that as the shell, or is it a forced command? Show the remote `authorized_keys` file (add the additional info to your question, don't put it in a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue due to permission on home directory:

home directory ~, ~/.ssh directory and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the remote host must be writable only by the user used 700 or 755, 775 will not work.

private key file (on the local host) neet to be readable and writable only by the user used: rw——-, 600.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with quoting. Simply remember that whenever you want to execute a shell command over ssh then it is received by the remote shell (e.g. Bash) as, `/bin/bash -c <command-line>`. You need to have only one pair of quotes:

```
ssh remo-tehost "echo test  >> /home/alarmstest.log"
```

This pair is important to prevent the local shell, that is, the one you using to executing the command-line, from interpreting the parameters.

Comment: [user@local-host ~]$ ssh  remote-host"echo test  >> /home/alarmstest.log"
"echo test  >> /home/alarmstest.log" isn't allowed to be executed with process or redirect controls

this issue is on the remote host, i test this with old server as remote host and worked fine

Comment: What is the shell that you log into by default on the remote host? Is it `/bin/bash` or something else?

Comment: **isn't allowed to be executed with process or redirect controls.
is there any solution to this? 
on remote server it is -bash (/usr/bin/bash) shell, i have got it by echo $0 command