# Why can't I execute an SSH command on a remote host?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I'm accessing a remote host via a jumpbox. I can easily access the remote host if I access it via an ssh shell:

```
ssh remoteHost

Last login: Tue Feb 16 12:56:26 2016 from xx.xxx.xx.xx

remoteHost:user:~$ ls

<shows all the stuff>
```

but when I try to execute a command via the SSH command line option, I always get:

```
ssh remoteHost ls

"ls" isn't allowed to be executed.

Killed by signal 1.
```

I can successfully execute the ssh command on *some* hosts, but not others.

Is this a setting that can be configured on the server, i.e. "allow remote ssh commands" or something similar?

FWIW, I did have a look at [How to enable using commands on remote host using ssh without password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174470/how-to-enable-using-commands-on-remote-host-using-ssh-without-password), but I'm pretty sure my problem is not related to quoting as the only answer on that question seems to indicate.

Update:

On the remote host, I have an authorized_keys2 file that contains something like this:

```
ssh-rsa <encrypted stuff> jumpbox_user@jumpbox
ssh-rsa <encrypted stuff> jumpbox_user@mydesktop
```

My ssh/.config file looks like this:

```
Host remoteHost
  HostName remoteHost
  User user
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumpbox_user@jumpbox_host
  ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Comment: The hosts behind the jumpbox all run Red Hat, if that makes a difference.

Comment: On the remoteHost, can you show us the content of the `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file?

Comment: @EightBitTony - added in the question, thanks.

Comment: how do you connect to the servers behind jumpbox? What is your configuration? Are you sure you are not running the command on jumpbox? Does it work directly if you execute the command from shell?

Comment: On remoteHost is there a /home/user/.ssh/rc file (or an /etc/ssh/sshrc file) and do they contain anything interesting?

Comment: @EightBitTony - No, only authorized_keys2 and known_hosts. No sshrc file in /etc/ssh either.

Comment: What kind of ssh daemon has that jumpfox? Dropbear does not execute ssh arguments...

Comment: @Jakuje - I connect via a ProxyCommand in my ssh/.config. Yes, when I log in with the shell everything works as expected.

Comment: Can you include your .ssh/config file in the question.

Comment: @EightBitTony - done, but I'm having this problem even when I execute the command from the jumpbox itself, so I doubt it has anything to do with the jumpbox config. I also now found a host where the remote command *does work* via the jumpbox, once again convincing me this is a setting on the remote host.

Comment: maybe this is helping? This is how to restrict commands - you have something like this in config files? http://www.cmdln.org/2008/02/11/restricting-ssh-commands/ in authorized_keys you should have a line in your authorized keys like this no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty,command=”/home/backup_user/bin/authprogs”. especially command= part which is allowing what to be run.

Comment: Judging from that error message, you're probably running `sudosh` as your shell on the remotes. Talk to the admins there to expand the allowable set of commands.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your ssh line with the `-t` option and make sure your remote command is delimited by ' as that tells ssh to run the command on the remote host, making your line much more error-proof.

```
ssh user@remoteHost -t 'ls'
```

FYI: The -t option enables pseudo-terminal allocation which actually simulates opening an SSH terminal then typing the command, then outputting STDOUT and exiting - which is exactly what you did manually as you mentioned.

According to the SSH man-page:

> -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to exe‐
> cute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine,
> which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu ser‐
> vices.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if
> ssh has no local tty.

References:

[SSH man page](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ssh1.html#:%7E:text=-t%20%20%20%20%20%20Force%20pseudo,no%20local%20tty.)

[What is Pseudo TTY-Allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900760/what-is-pseudo-tty-allocation-ssh-and-github)